# Brun's theorem - notation

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, oeis

The series $1,3,6,9,12,14$ represent the first six terms of the series A168045 on OEIS. The formula for this says $a_n = 2n + n / log n + O(n / (log n)^2)$. I do not understand this notation. What base log is this, and how do we compute $O(.)$? Isn't $O(.)$ an order?

Looking a bit more at this, this is derived from some Brun's Theorem.

Alternately, is there an analytical expression for this?

Comment: Note that $a_n$ must be an integer. So this cannot be equal to your formula. The base is always $e$, but doesn't matter, since $\log_a(x)=O(\log_b(x))$.

Comment: That's just telling you how quickly the terms grow, it is *not* a formula for the $n^{th}$ term.  The definition of that sequence appears to be [A167707 +n](http://oeis.org/A167707).

Comment: @lulu exactly. however,$ n + n / log n + O(n / (log n)^2) $ does not lead to integer values either...

Comment: Perhaps you intended that comment for @DietrichBurde?   In any case, since the formula is just a growth indicator, it makes no difference if it yields integer values or not.  Once again, it is a bound on the growth, not an exact formula.

Answer (score 2):

The log is the natural logarithm.  $O(.)$ is ["Big-O notation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) describing the behaviour as $n \to \infty$.  That is, the formula says there exist numbers $N$ and $C$ such that
$$ \left| a_n - 2 n - \frac{n}{\log n} \right| < C \frac{n}{(\log n)^2} $$
for all $n > N$.

Comment: However, how does this expression then lead me to *exact* values of the series as claimed by the OEIS?

Comment: @bissi, no, as in other comments and in this answer, it is _not_ an exact formula, but would be called an _asymptotic_ formula, meaning that it there is an _error_ left over after giving a good approximation, but/and the error is smaller than the "main term" as the parameter "$n$" goes to $+\infty$.

Comment: @bissi As Paul (and Robert) indicated, writing $a_n=2n+n/\log n+O(n/(\log n)^2)$ has the same meaning as $a_n-2n-n/\log n \in O(n/(\log n)^2)$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Matters_of_notation for a discussion about Big-O notation.

Comment: I know what the Big O notation means. I'm interested in an analytical expression for this series.

Comment: That is very unlikely to exist.